# PHP open_ssl, ftp_ssl_connect on Windows

Tags: php, windows, php-openssl

I have a function in php that needs to connect to ftp using ftp_ssl_connect. Iam using windows seven and as per the answers from google I need to rebuild the php to include the ssl functions. Now my question if is there a way to enable ssl on Windows without rebuilding php? Or is there a donwloadable version where ssl already included for windows?

thanks

Comment: Compiling PHP on Windows is the kind of thing you don't want for your worst enemy. There're many WAMP bundles out there you can try (and I'm afraid this is not the place to get advice on that). Perhaps it's better to just use another function—of course, that depends on your exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP [doc](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php):

> **Note:** Why this function may not exist
>
> ftp_ssl_connect() is only available if both the ftp module and the
>   OpenSSL support is built statically into php, this means that on
>   Windows this function will be **undefined in the official PHP builds**. To
>   **make this function available on Windows you must compile your own PHP
>   binaries**.

Emphasis mine.

---

However, I've downloaded PHP binary for windows from  official php.net and I noticed there's a specific DLL (ext/php_openssl.dll) for openssl. It means maybe it's not necessary rebuild PHP in order to get openssl working. Just remember add an entry for the dll in php.ini file. 
It should be something like this:

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "ext"

...
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

**NOTE**

*I haven't tested the above case.*

Comment: Nope, `ftp_ssl_connect()` is still unavailable because SSL is not statically built (you're even loading the DLL yourself).

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 7.0, the core FTP extension on Windows is by default built with OpenSSL support. In the earlier PHP versions, while SSL support is possible, it is not provided with the standard builds for various reasons. The only solution for PHP 5 is to make a custom build of PHP, while the standard PHP 7.0 builds on windows.php.net provide the ftp_ssl_connect() function.

Thanks.

Comment: I have downloaded the latest build and still receive the error.

Comment: Which exact error? Is php_ftp.dll loaded through php.ini?